# creating json format in php for autocomplete search

Tags: php, arrays, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i want to create json format in label and category.
    and i am not getting the code of the JSON format in PHP 
    how to do this

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

  $data = 'label:'. $key.','.'category:'.$value;
}
echo json_encode($data);


I want to something like :  
    "[{label:"a", category:"1"},{label:"b", category:"2"},{label:"c", category:"3"}]
```

jQuery.ui.autocomplete not work ::

var test_url = Drupal.settings.url + '/all_list';

```
jQuery(".class").catcomplete({
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 3,
       // source:data
        source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type : 'Get',
        url: test_url,
        success: function(data) { console.log(data);}

      });
   }

    });
```

i have getting via console.log(data);

```
[{"label":"a","category":1},{"label":"b","category":2},   {"label":"c","category":3},{"label":"d","category":4},{"label":"e","category":5}]
```

Comment: Note that you can simply use `json_encode()` on an array. You don't have to convert it to any special string format.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    $data .= 'label:'. $key.','.'category:'.$value; //you have missed this concatenation part
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$final = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  $final[]=["label"=> $key,"category" => $value];
}
echo json_encode($final);
?>
```

output is :

```
[{"label":"a","category":1},{"label":"b","category":2},{"label":"c","category":3},{"label":"d","category":4},{"label":"e","category":5}]
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/663626

Comment: Hi, Rishi

var test_url = Drupal.settings.url + '/all_list';

    jQuery(".class").catcomplete({
         delay: 500,
      minLength: 3,
        // source:data
         source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
            type : 'Get',
            url: test_url,
            success: function(data) {}

          });
       }

     });

Comment: here my ajax call i am getting json data in console.log but autocomplete not work